# Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 gnome-control-center crashes and can't open settings

Tags: gnome, software-center, 16.10

I have just installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 for the first time on my Lenovo 710 15' Laptop (the model with the 940MX Graphics). I finally got it to boot after booting with acpi=noirq (stating this just in case it has any significance).

Everything seems to go find and work. However, after a while of use, I will get a pop-up saying there was an internal error. I try to then open the settings, and I cannot because gnome-control-center has crashed.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having this same issue as of today. Cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and I realized that I just upgraded my NVidia drivers. I reverted back to the previous version and the issue was resolved.

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I also face the same issue and I tend to keep having troubles with my nvidia driver...
what version did you have installed and what version ended up working for you?
thanks

Comment: I just upgraded to 384, but if I remember correctly it was the 2nd driver before this one that I had an issue with (I'm not at home, so I can't check right now). But every so often I have an issue with being able to log in. As soon as I log in the screen goes black and I get kicked back to the login screen. Only purging the drivers and reinstalling fixes it. I have no idea what that's about.

Comment: yea I was used to have the same issues. not it just stopped working. when I try to install nvidia-38* it says that everything went well then I reboot and it's not installed. I don't understand how can such a common scenario be so hard to maintain